# Angular subscription doesn't fire

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm currently trying to make a parent component and child component.

When child component is loading data from REST, the parent should display a loading gif. Here is the code:

**common.service.ts**

```typescript
    import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
    import { Subject } from "rxjs";

    @Injectable()

    export class CommonService{
    private isLoadingSource = new Subject<boolean>();

    public isLoading$ = this.isLoadingSource.asObservable();

    setLoading(loading: boolean) {
        this.isLoadingSource.next(loading);
        console.log(loading);
    }
    }
```

**app.component.ts**

```typescript
      import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
      import { NavService } from "./core/nav";
      import { CommonService } from "common.service";

      @Component({
      selector: "app-root",
      templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
      styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"],
      providers: [
        NavService,
        CommonService
      ]
      })
      export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      public loading: boolean = false;

      constructor(private commonService: CommonService) {
        this.commonService.isLoading$.subscribe(next => {
            this.loading = next;
            alert(next);});
      }
      }
```

**child.component.ts**

```typescript
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, ViewChildren, QueryList } from "@angular/core";
    import { CommonService } from "common.service";
    @Component({
      selector: "child",
      templateUrl: "./child.html",
      styleUrls: ["./child.scss"],
      providers: [
        CommonService
      ]
    })
    export class child implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
      constructor(
        private commonService: CommonService,
      ) { }
      public beforeLoading(): void {
        this.commonService.setLoading(true);
      }
      public afterLoading(): void {
        this.commonService.setLoading(false);
      }
    }
```

When I run the code the console logged some true and false records, but the listener in `app.component.ts` doesn't receive a response.

There is no alert message popping up.

Answer (score 4):

The reason this doesn't work is because you provide the service, not as a singleton but as seperate instances per component. It is instantiated twice and thus does not share it's data.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
```

Try adding this to your service and remove the

```
 providers: [CommonService]
```

from both child and app component.

This provides the service at the root level of your application and is used as a singleton.

I've created a working stackblitz that you can look at:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wpdyv9?file=src/app/child.component.ts

Comment: Hi Emanuel,
Thanks for help and it works!
Anyway, there is one thing that you missed which is the common.service.ts also need to add the injectable, otherwise the app.component.ts will occur an error which is: app.component.html:3 ERROR Error: NullInjectorError: No provider for CommonService!

Comment: Glad it works, I don't understand what I missed :) I did say you need to have injectable in your service.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I was trying the get a variable from service updated on more than one component. I followed documentation and tutorials, but nothing. With this answered, I realized that I was using different instances of the service. When I removed the service from providers, it worked as a charm.